# Can smart contracts reuse RequestIds provided by Chainlink to retrieve results/data?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

Based on my understanding, Chainklink jobs are meant to execute fulfillment callback functions once certain conditions are met. Is there a Chainlink function that can retrieve the results/data of said RequestId/job instance for a smart contract?

Thank you in advance for any insight or feedback.

edit:

Say, for example, when you make a request using Chainlink's Any API functionality, you want to retrieve **private data**, so in the callback function, it would be ideal for retrieving said data if you could pass it to the front-end/web3 without emitting it to the blockchain(without storing the data on the blockchain), but returning the data like a *view* or *pure* function.

What Chainlink has documented:

```
function requestPrivateData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);

    req.add('get', 'https://example.com/api/endpoint');
    req.add('path', 'data');

    return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
}

function fulfill(bytes32 requestId, bytes memory data) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) returns (bytes memory) {
    // manipulate data then return
    return data;
}
```

What I'm looking for in terms of functionality, and not just rely on callback functions to return results:

```
function getJobResult(bytes32 requestId) public view returns (bytes memory) {
    if (jobResults[requestId].status == Status.Success) {
        return getChainlinkResponse(requestId);
    } else {
        revert StatusError("Job not completed");
    }
}
```

I understand Chainlink wants to emit the process; that's fine, but it would be ideal for returning private data without emitting it, as the function above would, in theory.

Please advise if I should clarify anything! Thank you!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? are you referring to Chainlink Any Api or custom External Adapters, or VRF or one of the other services?

Comment: @ZeusLawyer Hello, thank you for taking the time to review my question! I edited the question to add more clarity at your request. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help @Marcin! A couple more questions just to make sure I'm fully following your code snippet there..what is `jobResults`? A mapping in your contract? If so how is it getting status results? 

I understand that your core question is can I have Any API return *private data* in a way that is not emitted (hence not recorded on the blockchain).  Mechanically, trying to work out how you'd get status responses without some form of storage of request / response lifecycle state.  In that vein- what will getChainlinkResponse() query in your approach?